# Does code signing help avoid the red SmartScreen banner in IE 9/10?

Tags: installation, code-signing, digital-signature, authenticode

We've released a new application but we're getting reports that when users try and download it in Internet Explorer, they get a red error message after they choose to save or run the EXE file:

[image: Smart screen banner]

What we want to know is, how can we stop this red version of the banner appearing for IE users? Will code signing persuade IE to instead show the yellow banner which gives the users the option to run or save the file?  And if so, is it possible to get a temporarily/trial certificate (not self signed) to test this with? Self signing doesn't seem to help.

**Edit:**
I've also noticed Google Chrome has a similar banner and effectively the same problem that the users will be scared off installing the file.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is entirely controlled by SmartScreen Filter from IE. You cannot control it when creating the setup packages, not matter the tool you use to author them. Here are more details:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/SmartScreen-Filter-frequently-asked-questions-IE9

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/When-to-trust-a-software-publisher-IE9

What I can recommend is to use the same name of the setup file for future versions, i.e. do not change it for every version and digitally sign the package using a code signing certificate. When more users will download the package the browsers will gather statistics and start trusting your file.